# Is there an open source lib for scanning and decoding a QR code on desktop?

Tags: desktop, webcam, qr-code

I am looking for code demonstrating how to both capture and decode a QR code on a desktop (Windows/Linux) using a web cam. Is there such available? (only found a lib to decode QR codes, but not capture them)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) will work just fine, if you are a) willing to work in Java on the desktop, and b) can write the glue code to get frames off the webcam. The rest is done by the library once you feed it those images.